# Unexpected behaviour while adding an item to an array in a BSON document that has come from Mongoose query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bson

after I get a result from mongoose, I am trying to add some more stuff to it, so I am adding a _ext field that is an extended replica of what i got from query:

```
    [...]
    var schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: Number,
        member_of: {type: [Number], required: true }
    });
    var User = mongoose.model('users', schema);
    User.findById(1, function(err, result){     
        console.log(result);
```

Output:

{_id: 1, member_of: [1], __v: 0}

```
        var user = result.toObject();
        delete user.__v;
        user._ext = {};
        user._ext._id = user._id;
        user._ext.name = '';
        user._ext.displayName = '';
        user._ext.imageUrl = '';
        user._ext.member_of = [];
        for (var i in user.member_of) {
            var temp = {};
            temp._id = user.member_of[i];
            temp.name = '';
            temp.displayName = '';
            temp.imageUrl = '';
            user._ext.member_of.push(temp);
        }
        console.log(user);
```

Output:

Actual:

{   _id: 1,
    member_of: [1],
    _ext: 
    {   _id: 1,
        name: '',
        displayName: '',
        imageUrl: '',
        member_of: [[Object]]
    }
}

Expected:

{   _id: 1,
    member_of: [1],
    _ext: 
    {   _id: 1,
        name: '',
        displayName: '',
        imageUrl: '',
        member_of: [{_id: 1, name: '', displayName: '', imageUrl: ''}]
    }
}

```
        [...]
        });
```

Look member_of array in _ext structure: I got `[Object]` instead of `{_id: 1, name: '', displayName: '', imageUrl: ''}`. What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're doing nothing wrong, but `console.log()` only recurses into nested objects up to a certain depth:

```
> console.log([[[ "test" ]]])
[ [ [ 'test' ] ] ]
// add one more level, and...
> console.log([[[[ "test" ]]]])
[ [ [ [Object] ] ] ]
```

Try converting your object to (pretty-printed) JSON:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
```

Or, alternatively, use a formatting string (output won't be as pretty though):

```
console.log('%j', user);
```

Or use `util.inspect` with an specified depth (where `null` means `infinite`):

```
var inspect = require('util').inspect;
console.log(inspect(a, { depth : null }))
```

Comment: @robertklep That's likely the solution to a problem I've been having with understanding mongoose output. Thanks.

Comment: @cathy.sasaki yes it's very confusing when you don't know `console.log` is limited that way, I found out the hard way myself some time ago (and remembered ever since :)